# Как получить значение return из хранимой процедуры?

Tags: c#, sql

В sql ХП выглядит так

```
 ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[добавление_ос] 
        (@штрихкод nvarchar(30),
         @код_сотрудника int )
     AS
     begin
       INSERT INTO dbo.tObjectOS(sShtrihKodOS)
    VALUES (@штрихкод)
    END
    BEGIN
    SET @kodos = @@IDENTITY 
        INSERT INTO dbo.tZakreplenieMatLicOS(iKodOS,iKodSotr)
    VALUES(@kodos,@код_сотрудника)
        END
        RETURN @kodos
```

А это уже в студии

```
public class DobProc : Connect_
{
    public void dob_os(string shtrih_kod,  int KodSotrudnika, ref bool temp)
    {
        try
        {
            ConStr();
            SqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "[добавление_ос]";
            com.Parameters.Add("@штрихкод", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
            com.Parameters["@штрихкод"].Value = shtrih_kod;

            com.Parameters.Add("@код_сотрудника", SqlDbType.Int);
            com.Parameters["@код_сотрудника"].Value = KodSotrudnika;

            Connect();
            int tmp = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (tmp != 0)
            {    
                int pr= 0; // Как мне получить значение return и его тут присвоить? Или какие нибудь другие способы, подскажите?

                MessageBox.Show("Добавление успешно выполнено", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            EndConnect();
        }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
...
SqlParameter retValue = com.Parameters.Add("@kodos", SqlDbType.Int);
retValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;   // "направление" параметра
int tmp = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (tmp != 0)
{    
    int pr= (int)retValue.Value;
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё несколько способов:

1. Возвращать значение используя вместо оператора `return` оператор `select`. И в приложении забирать значение из первой строки первого столбца полученной выборки;
2. Использовать класс `SqlDataReader` и функцию `Read()`.